# Call a rail's action after PDF generation process is completely finished. - PRAWN + RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I'm using PRAWN to generate a pdf book in Rails.
In my application, I need to find the file-size of thus generated pdf book. So, I'm looking for a way that calls another action (which evaluates the file size ) when the pdf generation process is completely finished. 
Is there a way which I can put the code at the end of Prawn file that calls that action ? Or any another option - which waits until the pdf generation process is over and then calls that action ?

Any sort of hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth trying [resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) out for this sort of thing

Answer (score 2):

In Rails, an `action` is a public instance method on a controller which serves as an endpoint to which certain matching HTTP requests are routed. An `action` is intimately tied to the here-and-now of the HTTP request for which the `action` is the endpoint and the HTTP response which the `action` is building.

This may be semantics, but you don't want to call an action after completion of a long-running background job.

Instead, whatever that code is that needs to run after completion of a long-running background job, that code should be in the model or in some utility class.

See delayed_job and resque for implementations of background job queues/runners that are simple to use in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

[delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) also allows you to create asynchronous jobs